# Can't open R Studio after the last version installation

Tags: r, windows

I have tried to install tidyverse package using

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

RStudio had some problems with installations. Functions from tidyverse did not work, also other functions stopped working, for example, I still can't use *library(). * I deleted all the libraries connected to R and uninstalled RStudio, then I downloaded R and RStudio once again. When I started it, following problem report appeared:

````
## R Session Startup Failure Report

### RStudio Version

RStudio 2022.07.2+576, "Spotted Wakerobin" (e7373ef8, 2022-09-06) for Windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

### Error message

The R session had a fatal error.

2022-12-01T14:51:49.201211Z [rsession-1] ERROR r error 4 (Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : |||  cannot open the connection|||) [errormsg: Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : |||  cannot open the connection|||]; OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::r::exec::evaluateString(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,struct SEXPREC **,class rstudio::r::sexp::Protect *,enum rstudio::r::exec::EvalFlags) src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:375


### Process Output

The R session exited with code 2. 

Error output:

```
[No errors emitted]
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

### Logs

*C:/Users/1/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-1.log*

```
) [errormsg: Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open the connection
]; OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::r::exec::evaluateString(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,struct SEXPREC **,class rstudio::r::sexp::Protect *,enum rstudio::r::exec::EvalFlags) src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:375; LOGGED FROM: int __cdecl rstudio::r::session::RReadConsole(const char *,char *,int,int) src/cpp/r/session/RStdCallbacks.cpp:299

```
````

What should I do? R 4.2.2 is working properly, but I still can't download and use some packages (tidyverse and Openintro for example). I use Windows 8.1.

I deleted all the libraries connected to R and uninstalled RStudio, then I downloaded R and RStudio once again. R 4.2.2 is working properly, but I still can't download and use some packages (tidyverse and Openintro for example).

Comment: The OS is likely the issue.

Comment: You can’t run a recent RStudio on Windows 8. This is explained on the RStudio download page. Furthermore, it's unclear what exactly you deleted when you “deleted all the libraries connected to R” (that seems like a bad idea!). So that might have broken something. But as Phil said it’s also possible that the OS is an issue: did you pay attention to the R installation instructions for your OS, in particular the note about UCRT?

Comment: Try to separate the R problems and the RStudio problems. If you can open the built-in R GUI, can you install packages there? Can you use `library()` there? Are the problems only with RStudio, or also with your R installation?